# Problemas com barra de navegação

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Bom dia. Tenho uma tela com angular material em que simulo a flexnav do material design.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e quando desço o scroll fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo, somente no momento em que a tela é carregada fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já mexi bastante no Javascript e não consegui solucionar este problema. Desta forma, venho ver se alguém pode dar uma luz.

HTML

```
<header md-page-header>
    <div md-header-picture style="background-image:url(img/tst.jpg)"></div>

    <md-toolbar scroll id="toolbar">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-button class="md-tools" aria-label="Voltar">
                <img src="img/icons/arrow-back.svg" class="landTL" />
            </md-button>
        </div>

        <div class="main-fab" id="buttonEmail">
            <md-button aria-label="E-mail" class="md-fab md-primary">
                <img src="img/icons/email.svg" class="vertical-align-middle"/>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
</header>
```

JS

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {

    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

      /* header DOM element with md-page-header attribute */
      var header         = document.querySelector('[md-page-header]');
      /* Store header dimensions to initialize header styling */
      var baseDimensions = header.getBoundingClientRect();
      /* DOM element with md-header-title attribute (title in toolbar) */
      var title          = angular.element(document.querySelector('[md-header-title]'));
      /* DOM element with md-header-picture attribute (picture in header) */
      var picture        = angular.element(document.querySelector('[md-header-picture]'));
      /* DOM element with main-fab class (a DOM element which contains the main float action button element) */
      var fab            = angular.element(document.querySelector('.main-fab'));
      /* The height of a toolbar by default in Angular Material */
      var legacyToolbarH = 50;
      /* The mid-height of a float action button by default in Angular Material */
      var legacyFabMid   = 56/2;
      /* The zoom scale of the toolbar title when it's placed at the bottom of the header picture */
      var titleZoom      = 1.5;
      /* The primary color palette used by Angular Material */
      var primaryColor   = [255,202,50];

      function styleInit () {
        title.css('padding-left','16px');
        title.css('position','relative');
        title.css('transform-origin', '24px');
      }

      function handleStyle(dim) {
        fab.css('top',(dim.height - legacyFabMid)+'px');

        if ((dim.bottom-baseDimensions.top) > legacyToolbarH) {
            title.css('top', ((dim.bottom-baseDimensions.top)-legacyToolbarH)+'px');
            element.css('height', (dim.bottom-baseDimensions.top)+'px');
            title.css('transform','scale('+((titleZoom-1)*ratio(dim)+1)+','+((titleZoom-1)*ratio(dim)+1)+')');
        } else {
            title.css('top', '0px');
            element.css('height', legacyToolbarH+'px');
            title.css('transform','scale(1,1)');
        }

        if ((dim.bottom - baseDimensions.top) < legacyToolbarH * 5.8 && !fab.hasClass('hide')) {
            fab.css('top','30%');

            document.getElementById("buttonEmail").style.WebkitTransition = "all 1s"; // Code for Safari 3.1 to 6.0
            document.getElementById("buttonEmail").style.transition = "all 1s";       // Standard syntax
        }

        if((dim.bottom - baseDimensions.top) > legacyToolbarH * 0.3 && fab.hasClass('hide')) {
            fab.css('top',(dim.height - legacyFabMid)+'px');
        }

        element.css('background-color','rgba('+primaryColor[0]+','+primaryColor[1]+','+primaryColor[2]+','+(1-ratio(dim))+')');
        picture.css('background-position','50% '+(ratio(dim)*50)+'%');
        /* Uncomment the line below if you want shadow inside picture (low performance) */
        //element.css('box-shadow', '0 -'+(dim.height*3/4)+'px '+(dim.height/2)+'px -'+(dim.height/2)+'px rgba(0,0,0,'+(ratio(dim))+') inset');
      }

      function ratio(dim) {
        var r = (dim.bottom-baseDimensions.top)/dim.height;

        if(r < 0) return 0;
        if(r > 1) return 1;
        return Number(r.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/));
      }

      styleInit();
      handleStyle(baseDimensions);

      /* Scroll event listener */
      angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
        var dimensions = header.getBoundingClientRect();
        handleStyle(dimensions);
        scope.$apply();
      });

      /* Resize event listener */
      angular.element($window).bind('resize',function () {
        baseDimensions = header.getBoundingClientRect();
        var dimensions = header.getBoundingClientRect();
        handleStyle(dimensions);
        scope.$apply();
      });

    };
});
```

Fiz baseado [neste tutorial](http://codepen.io/jbltx/pen/KwQxBX).

Comment: Quando digo "Somente no momento em que ela é carregada" é porque quando eu movimento o scroll ele fica normal.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia tentar ocultar com css:

```css
seu-elemento {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-Y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz alterações na minha diretiva e funcionou.

```
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {

    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element(document).ready(function(){
          /* header DOM element with md-page-header attribute */
          var header         = document.querySelector('[md-page-header]');
          /* Store header dimensions to initialize header styling */
          var baseDimensions = header.getBoundingClientRect();
          /* DOM element with md-header-title attribute (title in toolbar) */
          var title          = angular.element(document.querySelector('[md-header-title]'));
          /* DOM element with md-header-picture attribute (picture in header) */
          var picture        = angular.element(document.querySelector('[md-header-picture]'));
          /* DOM element with main-fab class (a DOM element which contains the main float action button element) */
          var fab            = angular.element(document.querySelector('.main-fab'));
          /* The height of a toolbar by default in Angular Material */
          var legacyToolbarH = 50;
          /* The mid-height of a float action button by default in Angular Material */
          var legacyFabMid   = legacyToolbarH/2; 
          /* The zoom scale of the toolbar title when it's placed at the bottom of the header picture */
          var titleZoom      = 1.5;
          /* The primary color palette used by Angular Material */
          var primaryColor   = [255,202,50];

          function handleStyle(dim) {
            //fab.css('top',(dim.height - legacyFabMid)+'px');
            //fab.css('top', '90%');

            var dif = dim.bottom - baseDimensions.top;
            var difMeio = dim.height - legacyFabMid;

            console.log("Diferenca "+dif);
            console.log("toolbar "+legacyToolbarH);

            if (dif > legacyToolbarH) {
                element.css('height', dif+'px');
                fab.css({'top': difMeio+'px','position':'absolute'});
            } else {
                element.css('height', legacyToolbarH+'px');
                fab.css({'top':'20px','position':'fixed'});
            } 

            element.css('background-color','rgba('+primaryColor[0]+','+primaryColor[1]+','+primaryColor[2]+','+(1-ratio(dim))+')');
            picture.css('background-position','50% '+(ratio(dim)*50)+'%');
            /* Uncomment the line below if you want shadow inside picture (low performance) */
            //element.css('box-shadow', '0 -'+(dim.height*3/4)+'px '+(dim.height/2)+'px -'+(dim.height/2)+'px rgba(0,0,0,'+(ratio(dim))+') inset');
          }

          function ratio(dim) {
            var r = (dim.bottom-baseDimensions.top)/dim.height;

            if(r < 0) return 0;
            if(r > 1) return 1;
            return Number(r.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/));
          }

          handleStyle(baseDimensions);

          /* Scroll event listener */
          angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            var dimensions = header.getBoundingClientRect();
            handleStyle(dimensions);
            scope.$apply();
          });

          /* Resize event listener */
          angular.element($window).bind('resize',function () {
            baseDimensions = header.getBoundingClientRect();
            var dimensions = header.getBoundingClientRect();
            handleStyle(dimensions);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        });
    };
});
```